Late 90s / early 2000 European Thriller / Horror involving an Internet Predator?
Looking for a late 90s / early 2000 European Thriller / Horror involving an Internet Predator.
What I remember is;
This aired on SBS in the early 2000s, and I remember it being fairly new looking at the time of watching.
I believe this was made in the late 90s / perhaps 2000 to 2001. No later than that.
Lead actress was punk / gothic, with piercings or tattoos. I believe the plot was about her friend or relative going missing after chatting with someone online.
The lead actress is forced to strip in front of a webcam by the villain (no, this is not why I want to track this film down).
At some point, the lead is locked in a bathroom but escapes, left gasping for air.
I know this will probably be impossible to find, but I just thought I'd try.

Hrm...Possibly Strangeland with Dee Snider? Outside chance...

Thanks for the suggestion, but sadly Strangeland isn't it. I bumped into Strangeland in my quest for finding this unknown film, and actually will give Strangeland a watch. The film I'm after was non-English. I believe it may have been French, but am sticking to the description of European just in case.

Yeah, I figured it was a longshot. Strangeland is an effed up movie, but not too bad. I give it maybe 4/10.

@PerfectMachine is what language is the film in, btw you can simply say not english

I simply don't remember what language it was (it was 13 years ago), but I am convinced it was either Italian or French.

Movie identification questions must contain sufficient detail to be answerable. For help writing a good identification question, see: Identify-This-X Questions. Identification questions without an accepted answer will be deleted after 14 days.

Have you considered the Swedish movie The Girl with the Dragon Tattoo (2009)? I know you said no later than 2001, but it involves a punk/gothic lead actress being the victim of a sexual predator, and she eventually uses a webcam to get proof of his behaviour. Also, the ending involves escaping from a bathroom-like cellar. 
